# Multiple simulation zone bug in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, simulation-nodes

Simple case. I've a scene with a complex geometry nodes on a mesh but i simplified it for the post.

**Goal**

I need to use 2 simulation zones in my geometry node modifier but...

**Problem**

...the last simulation zone always "cuts" all the previous simulation zones job after the first frame. Do you know why?
[image]

**Detail**

I read all the docs about the simulation zone and the baking work behind but i didn't find anything that says i can't use multiple simulation zones in one geometry node modifier or use one simulation zone in multi geometry nodes modifier in the stack modifier of a mesh.
I didn't even find a check to tick in the program preferences.

**Tests**

If i use only one simulation zone all goes well but with 2 or more the system executes only the first frame (so in the image above only one shifting of the mesh by 0.1 on the X) and executes all the frames for the last simulazione zone.

I also tried to bake each **Simulation Output** node in a different custom path and if you do the same you see that for the first simulation node the baked frames go from 1 to 1...

[image]

...while for the second go from 1 to 250.

[image]

The same behavior if i use one simulation zone in one geometry node modifier and next adding another geometry node modifier with another simulation zone.

Bug or standard behavior?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Andrea.

Comment: from my experience, this is not possible. But I've found nothing which confirms that on the doc or other.

Comment: Thank you Lemon, I hope someone can find a solution or a confirm for this behavior.

Comment: Did anyone find why the behavior of this system? Thank you so much!